# How to Get a number From Call Log in android?

Tags: android, call, contacts

i want to call Call Logs Activity through intent for activity result. so to select a number from call logs and get this number in activity result. As this is possible in android. if so the please help me how to get a number from call logs. i use the following code but it doesn't work for me.

```
Intent showCallLog = new Intent(); 
showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(showCallLog,3);
```

this can't return to  activity back? please help me?

Comment: http://niravranpara.blogspot.in/2013/03/phone-call-historylog-programmatically.html

Answer (score 3):

I got this going using my own version.  i used a dialog and handed it the cursor to the call log. Here is the function:

```
public void getCallLog() {

    String[] callLogFields = { android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME /* im not using the name but you can*/};
    String viaOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    String WHERE = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " >0"; /*filter out private/unknown numbers */

    final Cursor callLog_cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, callLogFields,
            WHERE, null, viaOrder);

    AlertDialog.Builder myversionOfCallLog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getActivity());

    android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
            callLog_cursor.moveToPosition(item);

            Log.v("number", callLog_cursor.getString(callLog_cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)));

            callLog_cursor.close();

        }
    };
    myversionOfCallLog.setCursor(callLog_cursor, listener,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    myversionOfCallLog.setTitle("Choose from Call Log");
    myversionOfCallLog.create().show();
}
```